# ¿cómo deberia configurar el servicio de confirmación por correo electronico en MVC5 cuando no manda Email?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, email

```
        //este codigo es de AcountController.cs
// POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.NombreUsuario, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // Para obtener más información sobre cómo habilitar la confirmación de cuentas y el restablecimiento de contraseña, visite https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Enviar correo electrónico con este vínculo
                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirmar cuenta", "Para confirmar la cuenta, haga clic <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">aquí</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }
//este codigo es de IdentityConfig.cs
        // Si llegamos a este punto, es que se ha producido un error y volvemos a mostrar el formulario
        return View(model);
    }

public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            SendMail(message);
        }
       );
        // Conecte su servicio de correo electrónico aquí para enviar correo electrónico.
        //return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
    void SendMail(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        //Contenido especifico dentro del cuerpo del mensaje
        #region formatter
        string text = string.Format("Please click on this link to {0}: {1}", message.Subject, message.Body);
        string html = "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + message.Body + "\">link</a><br/>";
        html += HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(@"Or click on the copy the following link on the browser:" + message.Body);
        #endregion
        //direccion de envio configurada
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString());
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
        msg.Subject = message.Subject;
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(text, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(html, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));
        //cliente usado para enviar el mensaje
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", Convert.ToInt32(587));
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString());
        smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Send(msg);
    }
}
//esta sección va en WebConfig
  <appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="Email" value="men520055@gmail.com" />
<add key="Password" value="obviamente no les voy a mostrar mi contrseña" />
```

utilice este ejemplo de FOXLEARN, pero no envia y quisiera que por favor si alguien ha conseguido hacer funcionar en la version más reciente de VS 2017 y con C# 7.3 para poder terminar un proyecto que tengo o si notan algun error haganmelo notar.
!muchas gracias por su colaboracion¡. "11/12/2018"

Comment: Saludos Tobias, bienvenido a SOes, me alegra ver que ya tienes la medalla del recorrido, eso es buen signo, sin embargo me preocupa que no hayas visto este link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Para que tu pregunta tenga buena calidad, necesitas mostrar el código que tienes, lo que has intentado y el error que te da, si vas a pedir código, tu pregunta va a ser cerrada por los siguientes motivos: 1. No está claro lo que preguntas. 2. Demasiado amplia. 3. Basada en opiniones. Edita tu pregunta para darle la calidad necesaria y sobretodo que sea bien recibida. Buenas vibras :D

Comment: gracias por el dato, estaba modificando la imagen del codigo y no entendia muy bien como subirla hasta que pillé por fin donde se puede pegar, disculpa por no proporcinar la suficiente información y ser muy poco objetivo.

Comment: Copia y pega el código, te ayudamos a darle formato porque una imagen es una mala idea para mostrar código, se ve letra pequeña y dificulta reproducir tu escenario, hazlo simple para que la gente pueda verificar con facilidad tu código.

Comment: He hecho un servicio de correos y debo especificar el puerto no se si es eso que te falta yo utilizo el 25. Con el mismo servicio de gmail.

Comment: Coloca un breakpoint en: smtpClient.Send(msg); y mira qué error te genera.

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez muchas gracias por la informacion, pero no me ha funcionado

Comment: ¿Pero encontraste la forma de especificar el puerto?

Comment: Si es asi trata de depurar..

Comment: @fredyfx lo he intentado, pero no me arroja ningun error.

Comment: ¿Has habilitado imap y pop3 en el Gmail?

Comment: ¿Delivermethod? De esta forma no lo haz especificado

Comment: https://askgif.com/blog/122/seding-email-using-gmail-smtp-in-asp-net-mvc-application/ esta forma te puede servir..

Comment: https://askgif.com/blog/122/seding-email-using-gmail-smtp-in-asp-net-mvc-application/ esta forma te puede servir..

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez sí intente con el puerto 25, pero el que recomienda usar google es el puerto 587

Comment: @fredyfx Sí permiti el acceso a aplicaciones menos seguras a mi cuenta y la configuración de la que me hablas IMAP/POP(3) realmente no tiene mucho que ver a la hora de enviar mensajes desde la aplicacion, son configuraciones de gestion y recepcion atravez de clientes ya sean thunderbird, outlook, etc. y la configuracion SMTP es realmente la que necesito resolver

Comment: revisa si algún antivirus o firewall está bloqueando el puerto

Comment: @fredyfx deshabilite el windows defender, pero tampoco me ha funcionado así, intente tambien con el puerto auxiliar 465 que muestra en la guia de google

Comment: muchas gracias todos por la colaboracion, me rendi simplemente con el método e instalé SendGrid desde Nuget, lo configure y esta vez ha funcionado con este servicio que puede ser gratuito o de paga si tienes que enviar mas de 1000 correos al día.https://sendgrid.com/